# In C#, how do I get a distinct value from an IEnumerable using LINQ?

Tags: ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable variable that I want to extract a distinct value from. I know all the entries in the rows of the list have the same value, I just need to get that value.

The method returns an IEnumerable.

The row in the IEnumerable is defined as:
            QuoteCovId
            AdditionalInterestId
            AdditionalInterestsAffiliateId
            AdditionalInterestsLastName
            AdditionalInterestsBusinessAddrLine1
            AdditionalInterestsBusinessCity
            AdditionalInterestsBusinessState
            AdditionalInterestsBusinessZip

Sampel of code:

```
          IadditionalInterestData = AdditionalInterestData.GetAdditionalInterests(MasterPkgID, Requestor);

          // Using linq.
          var quotes = from ai in IadditionalInterestData
                       select Distinct(ai.QuoteCovId);

          // Iterate thru to get the 1 value.
          foreach (int QuoteCovId in quotes)
          {
              quoteID = QuoteCovId;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var quoteId = AdditionalInterestData.GetAdditionalInterests(MasterPkgID, Requestor)
                  .FirstOrDefault().Select(f => f.QuoteCovId);
```

Comment: +1 The key to this answer: "`all the entries in the rows of the list have the same value, I just need to get that value.`" That means you can just look at the first record, because it's the same as the others. No need to run a complicated distinct algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

But that method:

AdditionalInterestData.GetAdditionalInterests(MasterPkgID, Requestor);
returns me an IEnumerable which I will use further in my application. Which is what I need.

So how will your suggestion still give me that IEnumerable and give me the quote value which happens to be the same in the collection?

var quoteId = AdditionalInterestData.GetAdditionalInterests(MasterPkgID, Requestor).FirstOrDefault().Select(f => f.QuoteCovId);

Also, I just added your line of code as is and I get an error statement.

Comment: Assign it to a variable first:  `var data = AdditionalInterestData.GetAdditionalInterests(MasterPkgID, Requestor);` and then query with linq: var `quoteId = data.FirstOrDefault().Select(f => f.QuoteCovId);`  Then you'll still have access to your `data` variable.